# How to remove a Newly Created Apps section in Chrome Browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

It's a great feature that we can create new Apps sections and organize our apps. Renaming the section also nice. But how to remove a newly created Apps section? Default sections(Most visited/Apps) can be there, it's accepted. I have just played and created more sections as shown in the image:

[image]

Blank sections also not getting deleted. Trailing blank sections are getting deleted if I press Refresh button. But couldn't remove intermediate blank sections.Now how can I remove them?

PS: A nice explanation of using Chrome browser new tab page is [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95451)

Answer (score 1):

The existing tab will not change, but Open a new tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and the blank app sections will go away.

Comment: @Sathya-Ctrl + N opens new window but with blank apps sections. If I close Chrome and reopen they are all get vanished. So closing and reopening is the solution?

Comment: @arulappan yeah, for now. Consider [filing a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) with Chrome dev team